# Hide button if div empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to hide a button when a div is empty with no luck, why is the div empty? because via back-end wordpress i'm inserting a shortcode in it.

this is the code:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { if ( $(".whatever").parents("#content").length == 1 ){ 
 $('input#bt23').show();
}else { $('input#bt23').hide();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
///empty
</div>
<input type="button" id="bt23" class="bt23"  name="Button1" value="720p" /></body>
```

That's pretty much it, trying to get the button to disappear if there's no other div insider #Content, any ideas?

---

I just noticed that, maybe just maybe the div is not empty, it looks like it's empty but i think is filled with space.

So rather than comparing empty with filled, how would it be to compare filled with text and a specific div inside it?

---

like this:

```
<div class="content">
<div style="whatever">
<div class="video-wrapper" style="padding-bottom:56.2222222222%;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `text` or `html`:

### Without content

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  if ( $("#content").text() ){ 
    $('input#bt23').show();
  } else { 
    $('input#bt23').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<input type="button" id="bt23" class="bt23"  name="Button1" value="720p" />
```

---

### With content

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  if ( $("#content").text() ){ 
    $('input#bt23').show();
  } else { 
    $('input#bt23').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Content here</div>
<input type="button" id="bt23" class="bt23"  name="Button1" value="720p" />
```

---

### With spaces only

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  if ( $("#content").text().trim() ){ 
    $('input#bt23').show();
  } else { 
    $('input#bt23').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">   </div>
<input type="button" id="bt23" class="bt23"  name="Button1" value="720p" />
```

---

### Checking for a specific div

We can be a little creative here. Let's say we're looking for the `.video_wrapper` div inside the content. We can simply query for it, and if it's not found, the returned length will be zero, causing the input to hide.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("#content .video-wrapper"));
  if ($("#content .video-wrapper").length > 0) {
    $('input#bt23').show();
  } else {
    $('input#bt23').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div class="content">
    <div style="whatever">
      <div class="video-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="bt23" class="bt23" name="Button1" value="720p" />
```

### Checking for a specific div - plain JS

```js
function windowReady() {
  if (document.querySelector("#content .video-wrapper")) {
    document.getElementById('bt23').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('bt23').style.display = "none";
  }
};

window.onload = windowReady;
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="content">
    <div style="whatever">
      <div class="video-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="bt23" class="bt23" name="Button1" value="720p" />
```

Comment: it works perfectly here but not in my site... why would happen if there was a space inside the div

Comment: You can always `trim` spaces if you wish, though generally spaces *are* content.

Comment: Sure, can you show me what content you're checking against? (btw. added the trimmed version that ignores spaces inside)

Comment: Tried the new code but still anything, well when i set the video up, a div like this goes inside the content:

Comment: Another thing: `text` checks for textual content, and `html` checks for HTML markup as well... before showing me the content, you can try if it works with `html`, like this: `$("#content").html().trim()`

Comment: with the last code and text, it disappear even if there something or isnt, check the post

Comment: Nvm man, looks like you rocked it with html() try, anyway if you got another method let me know, ill keep setting up the buttons (are more than one) and ill tell you if something gets weird, and if you got the time of course.

Comment: Cool. I've just added another example where we're specifically looking for the video div inside. It all depends on what exactly you want to do. I believe all that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: is it posible to do this without jquery? @Shomz

Comment: Yes, of course, **anything** you can do in jQuery, you can also do in plain JS.

Comment: would you mind teaching me how, to do it in js or javascript? @Shomz

Comment: Sure, I've added a plain JS example using window.onload handler.

Comment: looks like isnt working hmmm, is there a way to use it with html() or like that?

Comment: well i apologize, it does work, but its really slow because it waits untill everything in the webpage is ready and then acts, is there a way to make this quicker as in document.ready?

Comment: You can just call that function just before the end of your body tag, no waiting then.

Comment: tried that but it waits untill the video is loaded :/ @Shomz

Answer (score 0):

You trying to accomplish something like this?

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   if ( $("#content").html() == '' )
   { 
     $('input#bt23').hide();
   }
   else { 
     $('input#bt23').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: nope it doesnt hide the button in my site dont know why

Answer (score 0):

well first of all this should be handled server sided in PHP, you should check there if any contend comes out. failing to do that there is a jquery solution.

```
if($.trim($("#content").text()) == ""){$("#bt23").hide();}
```

Comment: Nothing it doesnt hide.

Comment: Well onviously you have to put this in a document ready statement. And check for syntax errors as I an writing this on my phone :)

Comment: Thanks man, i tried it how you say but it dissappears even when the div is filled with other divs.

Comment: Btw. not sure if you know or just missed it because you're on the phone, but you can also use the trim method on the result string: `$("#content").text().trim()`  Makes a bit more sense in my head :)

Comment: hmm yes true that don't know what I was thinking