# How to enable button if div not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div and and button near the div:

```
<div id="tempData"></div>
<input type="button" text="status" disabled>
```

When page load the button is disabled.

At some point I add elements programmatically to div when div not empty it has to be enabld.
How can I make button enabled when div not empty and disabled when it empty?

Comment: Enable it in whatever logic is adding elements to the div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide button if div empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423716/hide-button-if-div-empty)

Comment: This SO post contains some great ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665466/using-an-if-statement-to-check-if-a-div-is-empty

Comment: With CSS: `#tempData:empty + input { pointer-events: none; }` (although, honestly, it's probably a bad idea).

Comment: @DavidThomas doesn't stop tab focus from getting to the element.

Comment: @rlemon: hence “*…it’s probably a bad idea.*” :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure javascript:

First check empty when your triggering action occurs, whatever that may be:

```
function whatevertriggeredthis(){
    if(document.getElementById("tempData").innerHTML === ""){

       // Give the button an ID then enable it
       document.getElementById("status_button").disabled = false;

    }
}
```

JQuery Version:

```
$("#tempData").on("change",function(){
   if($(this).text() !== ""){
      $("button").prop("disabled",false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function yourFunctionToUpdateDiv(){

  //YOUR CODE TO ADD/REMOVE DIV CONTENT
  //...
  //...
  
  
  if ($('#tempData').html()){ 
    $("input").prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{
    $("input").prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```